# the changed value does not show in Dom

Tags: reactjs, parameter-passing, state, setstate, react-props

I am learning React, in my test app, I make 2 identical sets of random colored array that will shuffle and change color every time I click on 'change color' button. however I can not seem to make the Dom updates my array colors even the values of colors change correctly.

```
import React from 'react';
class Card extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        const {r,g,b}=this.props.card
        this.state={
            style:{
                width:'100px',
                height:'100px',
                display:'inline-block',
                backgroundColor:`rgb(${r},${g},${b})`
            }
        }
    }
    onClick=()=>{
        const {r,g,b}=this.props.card
        console.log('color values of the card with index',this.props.id ,' is: ', r,g,b)
    }
    render(){
        const {style}=this.state
        return (
            <div style={style}>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>card test</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Card;
```

this is the picture of my problem

[image]

as you can see in the picture, the values change every time I click but the cards' color stay the same. however, it will work if I change the class based component into non class based component and set the style in render() instead of constructor, but I want to have a class component so I can pass the card I click to parent component.

Comment: Your onClick handler is essentially a no-op

Answer (score 4):

Is onClick triggering something else as well? Otherwise, don't see what would change the card's values, since the onClick is just logging.

Assuming the card prop is somehow changing correctly, I believe your issue is that your card prop is updating, but the state is set in the constructor and never updated.

Rather then setting a style value in state, I would just change to calculating style in render.

```
render() {
  const {r,g,b} = this.props.card
  const style = {
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    display: 'inline-block',
    backgroundColor: `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`
  }

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>card test</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You generally do not what to keep state that is easily derived from props to avoid situations like this.

Comment: the onClick of the 'change color' button will change the values of color, I just use the button on Card component to test if the values changed properly or not, and as you can see, the values of props changed properly,

Comment: @Nhat The props have changed but you are not changing the `state` to reflect the new values!

Comment: I tried to use setState like this                                                                  
      const {r,g,b}=this.props.card
      this.setState({backgroundColor:`rgb(${r},${g},${b})`})                                    but It did  not work. there must be something I did was wrong

Comment: @Nhat Are you implementing `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the state?